# Error in calling URL using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to call a file (sms.php) which is in xampp/htdocs directory. I want to access that file from my laravel project. It mentions that my laravel project folder also on that directory. I want to call that using ajax. My code shows **http://localhost:8000/localhost/sms.php** . (Checked using inspect and console) .How can I fix it ? 
Thanks in advance.

```
<script>

  $.ajax({
     url: 'localhost/sms.php',
     type: "get",
     data: {},
      success: function(data){ 
      alert('ok');
  }
});

 </script>
```

Comment: Prepend - `localhost/sms.php` - with - `http://`

Comment: Change the url to: `url: '/sms.php'` if that file is in the document root of the same project.

Comment: Thanks . but in sms.php file there is api which sends sms if I call that directly in URL. But how can I d that using ajax?

Comment: Check with chrome F12, tab Network and which error is it throwing, it's 404 ? 500 ? 303 ?.. and then doc laravel how to make ajax call

Comment: 404...............

Comment: Can you update your question to include your actual files- and folders-structure? And tell us which folder is your document root? The `sms.php` file needs to be in the document root, not outside. In a normal Laravel setup, you set `public/` to be your document root.

Comment: **sms.php** is in xampp/htdocs directory. And **laravel project**  is in xampp/htdocs/myproject directory. How can I access sms.php from my laravel project?

Comment: What folder is you XAMPP-server configured to use as document root? Ajax can only access files that are inside the document root. If `xampp/https` is the document root, then `/sms.php` should work. If the document root is a sub folder, you need to move the `sms.php` file.

Comment: Ok. I got this. Thanks. It was not clear to me. now it's ok